# iOS application not responding after Device turned off

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working with an application and i am new to this technology, so want some guidance .
When i testing my app on my device, it works great , but then i removed my iPhone from the Xcode6 and switched off the device. When i turns on the device and click on  my Application icon, it does not start , it is not responsive  and application not started.
Is here any issue with the application or we can't run the app(in developing phase ) after closed down the device and restart the device again.
Please have some clear answers.
Thanks,
Happy Coding

Comment: There should not be any problem, try closing the app from background and open again. It should be working.

Comment: Try removing the application and build it again.

Comment: @iphonic: sir can you please elaborate it . i am really not getting your words. How to close  the app from background and open again.Please explain.

Comment: @zemoon : sir, after removing and build the app , it works fine., but i want to ask without building it again. i want to run the app.

Comment: You should press the stop button in Xcode before you unplug the cable from your device. In the past, when you run the app using Xcode, then you unplug the cable, it can cause the app not respond.